# How to configure VM IPs on VMWare ESX Host

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx

I have rented a server from So You Start that runs VMware ESX 6.0 on it.
I have bought IPs to use them in my VMs bu t the problem is i cannot make them run VMs.

I did exactly what this guide says for Windows Server 2012 
http://docs.ovh.ca/en/guides-network-bridging.html

But still I do not have connectivity.

Assume that I have 123.456.789 ip and its net mask is 255.255.255.255
And its gateway is 987.654.254 (assuming that my host io is 987.654.321)
My configuration is exactly same link in this screenshot:

[image]

What I am doing wrong should I add a route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also :

- change the MAC address of your VM with the one given by So You Start (from ESXi admin client, see http://ask.xmodulo.com/static-mac-address-vmware-esxi-virtual-machine.html) ;
- configure the network card of your VM so that it can reach the external network (see http://www.tuto-it.fr/ESXvNetworks.php).

Comment: Yes MAC was the case, when i add MAC address manually everthing worked.